# How to set a Image Button's image xcode aplescript OBJC

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, user-interface, applescript

I am trying to change an Image Button's image object with this code using applescript.

I have tried this:

`property theButton : missing Value`

`on button_(sender)
set newImage to "example.png"
changeImage(newImage)
end button_`

`on changeImage(newImage)
set theImage to current application's NSImage's imageNamed_(newImage)
theButton's setImage_(theImage)
end changeImage`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
on changeSomeImage_(newImage, targetObjectOutlet, newText, targetLableOutlet)


set newImage1 to current application's NSImage's imageNamed_(newImage)
targetObjectOutlet's setImage_(newImage1)
targetLableOutlet's setStringValue_(newText)


end changeSomeImage_
```

Answer (score 0):

First clarify a few things:
Is the button connected properly? Do you want to change the image on click or before? That's what your code says. If you want to change image before do it in IB or in awakeFromNib method.

Is the buttons action linked properly? Either in IB if your on XCode or pure applescript objc:

```
theButton's setTarget:me
theButton's setAction:"changeImage:"
```

If linked you may use a log message to see if it works:

```
log "works"
```

This should bring you forward - otherwise please post more code

Comment: And please keep your posts together and don't add new posts for the same question!